# How to install GNU Emacs on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient, install

I can't find a clear tutorial for how to install GNU Emacs on Windows 10. Normally there are a few tricks required to get it running properly, so I thought I would ask here before trying one of the Windows 8 tutorials.

The specific “flavour” of Emacs is not particularly important.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  This is not yet a good fit for the site because it is either straightforward (follow the [install instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html)) or too open-ended ("what tricks do I need")?  Try installing and, if you run into specific problems, come back with discrete questions for the site.

Comment: Maybe the instructions you link to seem straight forward to you but not to me. On both the mirrors and the main page I am expected to know which file I want from the name alone. Maybe this is a simple request for somebody in the community but even giving the link to the install instructions helped.

Comment: Go for it, not much has changed since windows 8 for installing Emacs.

Comment: Can you at least tell me which zip file I should download?

Comment: There are more detailed instructions at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/README

Comment: Please clarify your question by incorporating your "Can you at least tell me which zip file I should download?" into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some [third-party Windows package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Windows) offer a straightforward installation of GNU Emacs on Windows 7+. Notes:

- Chocolatey requires an administrative shell access, whereas Scoop does not and makes installation portable.
- Both Chocolatey and Scoop install 64-bit Emacs on 64-bit host system.
- Both Chocolatey and Scoop automatically create corresponding shims so that Emacs can be called from the console via `emacs` (GUI version) or `emacs -nw` (terminal session).

## [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org)

#### Installation

Open *elevated* PowerShell and [install the `choco` package manager](https://chocolatey.org/install), then install [`emacs`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/Emacs) package:

```
choco install emacs
```

#### Launching

By default an icon is added to the start menu and the launcher can be found at `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\runemacs.exe`.

#### Updating

```
choco update emacs
```

#### Removing

```
choco uninstall emacs
```

## [Scoop](https://scoop.sh)

#### Installation

Open PowerShell and [install the `scoop` package manager](https://scoop.sh), then add [`extras`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras) repo (you will need to install `git` and `7zip` as well):

```
scoop bucket add extras
```

Install [`emacs`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras/blob/master/bucket/emacs.json) package:

```
scoop install emacs
```

#### Launching

By default an icon is added to the start menu into the Scoop Apps folder and the launcher can be found at `~\scoop\apps\emacs\current\bin\runemacs.exe`.

#### Updating

```
scoop update emacs
```

#### Removing

```
scoop uninstall emacs
```

Comment: On Windows10: `emacs64 not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.` -> with `emacs` it worked.

Comment: @AndreasL. I appreciate your feedback! Many things have changed since I wrote this answer which I now have rewritten from the ground up thanks to your comment. Currently, `cinst emacs` already installs `emacs-27.2-x86_64.zip` on 64-bit systems, and support for `emacs64` appear to be dropped, so I deleted this portion as irrelevant. Also, I added an alternative package manager Scoop for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

After reading many tutorials and readmes I was unable to install Emacs and `spacemacs` on my machine until now. It is super easy.

1. create a folder in a directory you wish to install (eg I'd like to install on drive `c:/`
2. add a new user variable named `HOME` and valued `to the created folder` (eg `c:/emacs/`
3. [download the latest version](http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/gnu/emacs/windows/) of Emacs
4. extract the content of the downloaded file into the folder you have created a couple of steps ago. (eg `c:/emacs/`)
5. open `runemacs.exe` located in `c:/emacs/bin/` directory; this would generate a folder named `.emacs.d` in `c:/emacs/`

**installing `spacemacs`**

6. quit Emacs
7. download [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs)
8. extract the content in the `c:/emacs/.emacs.d` directory
9. finally re-execute `runemacs.exe`.

> I've learned about the instruction in this [video](https://youtu.be/H3TzeUslFmo)

Comment: I think it's valuable to point out that HOME does not need to point to the place where you extract the content of your downloaded emacs zip file.